# Event Handler Not working after unsubscribing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, event-handling, windows-phone-8

I am calling one event handler on my `Page.onNavigatedTo` method like this

```
 oBooks.OnStatusChanged += oBooks_OnStatusChanged;
```

and its working fine And I am also unsubscribing this event handler on my page `OnNavigatedFrom` event like this

```
oBooks.OnStatusChanged -= oBooks_OnStatusChanged;
```

and its also working fine. But lets say its my MainPage and I navigate to some other page and then navigate back to this page and it try to subscriber my method but its not firing my eventhandler this time.

Where I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: [`Page.onNavigatedTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-TR/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto) is a method, not an event..

Comment: Further to what @SonerGönül has said, you should be using the `Loaded` and `Unloaded` events.

Comment: False. What Simon says **should not be done** in production. `OnNavigatedTo` is only called once for each time the page becomes active. `Loaded` can be fired multiple times given specific conditions you might not account for. Keep using `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom`.